# Compare two pandas series and remove duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two series:

```
ser1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
ser2 = pd.Series([4,5,6,7,8])
```

I want to compare ser1 and ser2 and then remove the duplicates and put the result into ser1 to have something like this:

```
>>> ser1
    out = 1 2 3
```

I tried `pd.concat` but this gave me the combination of the two series without removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(set(ser1).difference(ser2))
```

```
{1, 2, 3}
```